# Trying to display headers on multiple pages with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF to create a report from a Mysql database. The PDF is created fine but I would like to display the headers for each column at the top of every page for easier navigation. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to extend fpdf class, and implement your Ln function: every time you add a line, decrement counter of line number, and when is 0, add new page with header.

```
class _PDF extends FPDF
{
    var $_num_Rows = null;
    var $_heightCell = null;
    const NUM_ROWS = 48; // set number line in page

    function _PDF($orientation = 'P',$unit = 'mm' ,$page = 'A4')
    {
        $this->_numRows = self::NUM_ROWS;
        $this->_heightCell = 4; 
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);
        $this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $page);
    }
    public function init_numRows()
    {
        $this->_numRows = self::NUM_ROWS;
    }

    public function dec_numRows()
    {
        $this->_numRows--;
    }

    function Ln()
    {
        if ( $this->_numRows ) 
        {
            parent::Ln();
            $this->dec_numRows();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->addHeader();
        }

    }
    function addHeader()
    {
          $this->init_numRows();
          $this->AddPage();
          // ... 
    }

}
$pdf = new _PDF();
```